# I am trying to connect to local sql server using java code

Tags: java

I am getting the following error message when I try to connect to local sql server:

```
')' expected

<identifier> expected
----
```

(Alt-Enter shows hints)

the code thus giving me the error is :

```
String connectionUrl2=("jdbc:odbc:life","taf","taf4");
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: This ain't correct String declaration. `String connectionUrl2=("jdbc:odbc:life","taf","taf4");`

Comment: Here this might help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/ also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342339.aspx

Comment: try this DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSNNAME;user=username;password=password");

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how exactly you are trying to connect, but I suggest the following approach:

First, make sure you have the `sqlserver.jar` in your library. Afterwards:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

String userName = "your_username";
String password = "your_password";
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"+";databaseName=your_database_name";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

Read more from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx)

Comment: @ Raul Rene thanx, the string url that you have given me helped in solving my problem as i modified my code as beolw and it is no longer giving errs and its now importing :  String connectionUrl2=("jdbc:odbc:life;" + "databaseName=life;user=taf;password=taf4");

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then these statements will helpfull in connectining mysql. Just modify them according to your schema and table names, also you have to import mysql connector.

Connection connect=null;

PreparedStatement prep=null;

ResultSet result=null;

Statement state=null;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

connect=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentinfo?user=root&password=7585");
state=connect.createStatement();

prep=connect.prepareStatement("insert into student values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");